# How to make VS2010 quietly reload files in editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using sass for a project. I keep the CSS file open sometimes, but every time I save the .scss file VS asks me if I want to reload the CSS file, which I do. Is there any way of telling it to always reload the file type without prompting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tools/Options, navigate to Documents and check "Auto-Load changes, if saved."

EDIT: note that this will affect all files; as far as I know it's not possible to enable this selectively.  I'm sure an extension could change that!